# Subtracting positive numbers from denominator in an inequality.

Tags: inequality

When we have the following inequality:

$$\frac{a}{b+c} \ge \frac{d}{e+c},$$

with $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$

Then it seems to hold that

$$\frac{a}{b} \ge \frac{d}{e},$$

Is this correct? Does it also work in the other direction (iff)?

Comment: The answer by @Did answers the question,but I forgot to add some other conditions. I will ask a new question.

Comment: New question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725040/subtracting-positive-numbers-from-denominator-in-an-inequality-with-conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{\color{blue}{2}}\lt\frac{\color{green}{2}}{\color{green}{1}}\quad\&\quad\forall\color{red}{c}\gt1,\quad\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{\color{blue}{2}+\color{red}{c}}\gt\frac{\color{green}{2}}{\color{green}{1}+\color{red}{c}}$$

Comment: Could you switch back to the previous answer you wrote? It is just slightly more straightforward and answers the question.

Comment: No, thanks. $ $